# Changing Footer text in magazine pro theme wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I want to change the footer text and add my website name in it, how could I do so? I am using Magazine Pro Theme on Wordpress.

[image: Default footer of my Wordpress website with the Magazine Pro Theme]

Comment: Try asking your premium theme for support. This question is off topic for this site.

Answer (score 0):

Normally pro themes provide **documentation** for customizing it. You can find there the changing option. You can also check the **theme option** for that.

I hope you will get your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I must be present somewhere in the theme customizer. In mostly themes footer text will present in theme customizer under footer option

Comment: Then another method is to change it from the footer.php file. First of all, login to your WordPress dashboard and visit Appearance » Theme Editor from the left sidebar of your WordPress dashboard. On the right side, you'll see different theme files. From here open the Theme Footer file (footer.php). Now you can change the footer text from here. But before changing it, save the backup of code for restoration in case if you change the wrong code. If you still face any issues, send me the code which is present in footer.php and I'll guide you which code you have to change

Answer (score 0):

If you don't find the code in the theme customizer, then another method is to change it from the footer.php file. First of all, login to your WordPress dashboard and visit **Appearance » Theme Editor** from the left sidebar of your WordPress dashboard. On the right side, you'll see different theme files. From here open the Theme Footer file (footer.php).

[Check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYkOK.png)

Now you can change the footer text from here. But before changing it, save the backup of code for restoration in case if you change the wrong code. If you still face any issues, send me the code which is present in footer.php and I'll guide you which code you have to change.